# How does current start flowing in an induction circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Consider a simple induction circuit where there is just an A.C. source connected to an inductor.

Below is a graph showing how the emf generated by an A.C. source fluctuates with the rotation of the coil.

[image]

Let's say at $t=0$, one just starts rotating the coil of the A.C source in a magnetic field, such that emf (E) induced at $t=0$ is 0.

And since, $E=0$ at the start, I believe that current is just starting to flow in the circuit through the inductor.

[image]

But what we can see in the above graph is that the current is already at its peak at $t=0$.

How is it possible that peak current flows in the circuit at $t=0$ and $E=0$, when there's no prior energy stored in the inductor?

Answer (score 0):

That is only true if the inductor was previously magnetized. If you aren't moving the coil prior to the moment of t=0, the current Will start increasing at the same time as voltage, but the current Will be smaller than in the conductor.

Comment: It should be easier to understand if you had an AC voltage source  and a switch. Before you turn on the switch the current can't flow, so it's 0. Once you turn the switch, the current Will start flowing the same time as voltage and Will be increasing at the same time. However, once the voltage reaches the maximum value, the current Will still be increasing, even though the voltage is falling. That current Will come from the magnetic field created by the coil.This is where the phase shift is created between the current and the voltage. It operates that way from here on.